# What are features of html5 suited for IE6?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, internet-explorer-6

I am a beginner in html5. I am trying to design a website with html5/css3. What are features of html5 suited for IE6?
And how can we use html5 in IE6?

Comment: If you want to use the latest features that HTML5 & CSS3 incorporates then I think that you can forget about IE6 ever being able to render it

Comment: You shouldn't. IE6 is dead, let it rest in peace. Should you open the grave, throw IE7 and IE8 in it and close it back promptly.

Comment: How is it possible that IE6 still refuses to die? MS just released IE *11*. No-one is asking anymore how to make their Pascal app work in Windows 98.

Comment: @Bartdude very nice reply

Comment: I also would like to run it on MS-DOS ...  3.0 if possible ...

Comment: @user3011943 ie6 is just old. and every comment above this one is incorrect, bitter, and just meh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What are features of html5 suited for IE6?

The short answer here is: **None**.

IE6 has not had any new features added to it since it was released, it knows nothing about anything that was invented after it was released.

HTML5 was invented more than a decade after IE6 was released, so of course IE6 doesn't work with it.

There are a few third party libraries and scripts you can use to make some modern browser features work with IE6 ([see here](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills) for a fairly comprehensive list), but to be honest, a lot of stuff will never work, and even the things you can get working will be slow and buggy.

I strongly advise you not to bother even supporting IE6 for your site. (and frankly, that applies to IE7 too. your absolute minimum browser today should be IE8)

Finally, it's worth pointing out that Microsoft will completely stop all support for IE6 as of April next year. At that point, there will be no more security fixes for the browser, so anyone still using it is almost certain to get hacked fairly soon afterward. If you're still on IE6, I would advise you to upgrade immediately. If your customers are still on IE6, you should be telling them to do the same. (oh, and the same applies to Windows XP too)